# How do you check what files are inside an NSIS setup.exe?

Tags: nsis

In my NSIS script, I use this line:

```
 File "..\help\*.*"
```

My problem is that I have the help directory in my subversion repository (its constantly updated as we add new functionality). This means that the help directory contains a .svn directory.

I wish to view the contents of the setup.exe that NSIS created to verify that it does not have the .svn directory.

P.s. I experimented to see if NSIS recursively adds files when wildcards are used. It doesn't. But I want to verify this, hence the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These things are typically compressed files.
You could check with **7z**/**7-zip** to open the EXE archive.

---

As a record, after the comments below,
I'd like to point to my recent notes on the merits of **7-zip** at Superuser,
[**Compressing with RAR vs ZIP**](https://superuser.com/questions/5886/compressing-with-rar-vs-zip/5918#5918)

Comment: I tried with WinRar and the only thing it extracted was the .NET framework installer. Hmmm. Now that I think about it, maybe the .NET installer's header was read instead of my setup.exe. I'll remove the redistributables I have and try again.

Comment: Doesn't work. Removing the redistributables (basically compressed files such as the .NET installer) makes WinRar complain that the created setup.exe have "no archived files found"

Comment: I do not use WinRAR. Have you figured out the container this setup.exe has? If a (good) archiving tool says there are no compressed files, its usually just the executable code in there.

Comment: @nik I've just tried out all the possible Compression options (ZLIB, BZIP2, LZMA) and none of them allows WinRar to view the contents. I'm gonna try 7-zip just in case.

Comment: It only works in 7-zip, so I don't understand why you keep going on about WinRar.

Comment: 7-zip works. I'm ditching WinRar and telling everyone I know who use WinRar to switch.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than look at what's in your NSIS exe itself, just exclude the .svn directories so you know they'll never be in there.

Something like this will do the trick:

```
File /r /x .svn "..\help\*.*"
```

The `/x .svn` bit tells NSIS to exclude those directories.

Coincidentally, if you're not using the `/r` switch, then you're not adding files and folders recursively, so it wouldn't add the .svn subdirectories anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of unzipping, my suggestion is to look at the NSIS compilation log. It will tell you everything about files included. When doing changes in my NSIS scripts I always check the logs to make sure that everything is going according to plan. Streaming the log from the command line to a text file, then read it from your favorite editor.

Answer (score 0):

I use 7zip File Manager and the "Open Inside" command.